# TextView autoresizing like messaging apps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

I want to autoresize a TextView like a WhatsApp (messaging apps) to fit its content, I am loading this view from xib

This is my view (xib):

[image]

My code looks like:

```
class InputTextViewController: UIViewController{
  
  @IBOutlet weak var inputTitle: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var border: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var inputTextView: UITextView!
  @IBOutlet weak var underText: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var underLine: UIView!
  
  @IBOutlet weak var textViewHC: NSLayoutConstraint!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    inputTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 52).isActive  = true
    self.inputTextView.delegate = self

    }
}
extension InputTextViewController: UITextViewDelegate{
  
  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = CGSize(width: inputTextView.frame.size.width, height: .infinity)
    let estimatedSize = inputTextView.sizeThatFits(size)
    
    guard inputTextView.contentSize.height < 100.0 else{ inputTextView.isScrollEnabled = true; return }
    inputTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
    inputTextView.constraints.forEach{ (constraint) in
      if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
        constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

And finally I load my view in my story board in this container view (second
container):

[image]

I also have tried  this:

```
 textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Actually happens this:
[image]

TextView doesn't autoresizing when I adding text

what is wrong or missing in my code ?

Comment: Did you try searching on google? https://gist.github.com/novalagung/f303b4741a9a718ce047aa7d31d6df99, https://link.medium.com/unCQtgeDNjb

Comment: @CloudBalancing yes but doesn't work

Comment: But I see you did set height constraints. As directed not to